# Repeat method which returns object itself N times with Java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to implement following code in Java 8 style:

```
public Path getSomeParent(Path path, int depth) {
    Path someParent = path;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        someParent = someParent.getParent();
    }
    return someParent;
}
```

But no luck so far despite the fact that problem is so common as I think.

The first thought was to do it with `reduce` but `getParent()` is not associative, isn't it?

The second one was to use `IntStream.range(0, depth)` but I didn't find a way to do this task with it. It works well with methods returning `void` and that's it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first thought: simply don’t do this. The loop is perfect as it is.

Comment: You don't have any recursive calls in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *really* wish, you can use

```
return Stream.iterate(path, Path::getParent).skip(depth).findFirst().get();
```

but I don’t recommend it. Your original loop is fine.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted!
I will not replace my initial loop with it though (nevertheless, I wanted when asked), but in terms of theory it is very usefull.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of iterating you could use following snippet using the NIO 2 API (works as such also in Java 7).

```
Path path = Paths.get("/temp/some/dir/foo");
int depth = 2;

Path someParent = path.getRoot().resolve(path.subpath(0, path.getNameCount() - depth));

System.out.printf("%-10s: %s%n", "path", path);
System.out.printf("%-10s: %d%n", "depth", depth);
System.out.printf("%-10s: %s%n", "someParent", someParent);
```

**output**

```
path      : /temp/some/dir/foo
depth     : 2
someParent: /temp/some
```

Answer (score 2):

You still can use `reduce` for sequential streams as associativity is not necessary here:

```
return IntStream.range(0, depth).boxed()
        .reduce(path, (p, n) -> p.getParent(), 
                (p1, p2) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); });
```

Though it's not recommended as it will not work for parallel stream. *Some third-party libraries* provide a `foldLeft` method which would be more suitable in this case.

Comment: I reflected my thought about `reduce` in question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not known what is exactly "Java8 style", but, if we can use of the tail call optimization:

```
public Path getSomeParent(Path path, int depth) {
  if ( depth == 0 || path == null ) return path;
  return getSomeParent(path.getParent(), depth-1);
}
```

about if Java has or not tail call optimization, please, see this link: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044

Comment: Besides the fact that most JVMs don’t have tail call optimization, what’s the point of converting a loop to a recursion and hoping that the JVM will optimize it back to a loop?